# How to use Replicate in MS Access Database?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, replicate

In Sql Server for replication i use the following query

```
select replicate('0',5)
```

it gives result as

```
00000
```

what is the equivalent for this in MS Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `STRING()`

```
SELECT String(5, '0')
```